# RedisInsight contains malware

Tags: redis

I installed RedisInsight -win.1.2.0 a few days ago. I checked the Installation-Files with VirusTotal. Only one scanner reported an infection with a trojan. This seems to me as a false alarm. But today windows defender stopped the file. If i scan the RedisInsight.exe with VirusTotal today there are 23 findings!

Answer (score 5):

A new version of RedisInsight (v1.2.2) just got released and had this fixed.

It was actually a false-positive reported by certain antivirus vendors. Nothing malicious was shipped with RedisInsight! This was due to pyinstaller's issue.
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4633

The new version doesn't fall under this category.

Comment: Windows Defender immediately catches the 1.2.2 --> Trojan:Win32/Detplock

Comment: Hey @EgirusOrnila, can you please try to download the binary *somehow* and try to check it on virustotal.com and share the link if you could.

Comment: Yesterday when i wrote this comment, all scanners in VirusTotal are green, but now today there are 5 findings: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/1f2f628aee017094743a5635e4470bd4457eeeb798b3b145f4317193ab2b2687/detection

Comment: It seems like a false-positive again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and Google Chrome even refuses to download the new RedisInsight-win.1.2.1
I reported that to RedisLabs Contact but have no news so far.

As a workaround I added RedisInsight 1.2.0 installation folder to the exclusion list of Windows Defender, then launch again the installer and hit repair, and it seems to do the trick. 
However I would not recommend that because I took an unknown risk by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

my Google Chrome still detects RedisInsight 1.2.2 as infected:
[image]

Comment: Hey, @khelkun can you please check it again. It shouldn't happen now.

Comment: Sorry @Gnanesh redisinsght-win-1.2.2.msi either from this page https://redislabs.com/redisinsight/ or this page https://redislabs.com/download-center/more/ is still deleted by Google Chrome (actually it seems to be Windows Defender that deletes it) after download for virus detection. The download link from both pages points to https://downloads.redisinsight.redislabs.com/latest/redisinsight-win.msi
Windows Defender Report here: https://imgur.com/uUmqlkH

Comment: @Gnanesh If I force Windows Defender to accept the redisinsght-win-1.2.2.msi file then I can launch the installation and obtain this: https://imgur.com/ddkWp2s. If I "Run anyway" the installation, then RedisInsight seems to be installed correctly (note I previously removed the Windows Defender exclusion rule on RedisInsight installation directory), and so far Windows Defender doesn't seem to delete RedisInsight/redisinsight.exe. I also ran a Windows Defender scan on RedisInsight Installation directory, and it found no threats.

Comment: Can you please share the Security Intelligence version of your windows security (defender). Currently, `1.309.886.0` seems to be the latest and it doesn't report any signs of malware (both after downloading and after installing). I have tested it on one of the windows machine and aws windows server 2019 free trial version and both are having the latest security intelligence version.

Comment: @Gnanesh
Antimalware Client Version: 4.18.2001.7
Antivirus Version: 1.309.925.0
Antispyware Version: 1.309.925.0
Engine Version: 1.1.16700.3

I removed "Trojan:Win32/Detplock" from the allowed threats in Windows Defender then it stills detects "Trojan:Win32/Detplock" inside redisinsight-win-1.2.2.msi

Comment: The latest download link now downloads version 1.1.0, which is still blocked by Windows Defender.